# MYSQL PDO multiple database calls

Tags: mysql, object, pdo

I have a page that needs data from the same table in multi forms. Example below:

**Fixtures Table**
id
hometeam
awayteam
score
date

I need to return the following:

```
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE hometeam = 1;
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE awayteam = 1;
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE hometeam = 1 AND awayteam = 2;
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE hometeam = 1 or awayteam = 1;
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE hometeam = 2 or awayteam = 2;
```

My question is this seems strange to have multi calls when the data is almost the same. My question is is it better to do one call, and then try and create an object from that data. I don't know if that is possible but something like that would seem a better option?

I could return:

```
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE homteam = 1 OR hometeam = 2 OR awayteam = 1 OR awayteam = 2
```

And then try somehow to filter this into an object?

Any thoughts and help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about

SELECT * from fixtures WHERE homteam in (1,2) or awayteam in (1,2)

You can filter this data after you have gotten all the above data

This is essentially same as
SELECT * from fixtures WHERE homteam = 1 OR hometeam = 2 OR awayteam = 1 OR awayteam = 2

With more readability